# rsync auth failed when executed by salt

Tags: rsync, salt-stack

Rsync running normally via salt without password file, but when I added password file today, it didn't work anymore:

```
# salt 10.10.70.202 rsync.rsync rsync://10.10.81.71:9999/test /tmp/test/ delete=True passwordfile=/etc/rsync.passwd
10.10.70.202:
    ----------
    pid:
        105711
    retcode:
        5
    stderr:
        @ERROR: auth failed on module test
        rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1516) [Receiver=3.0.9]
    stdout:
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

It's using salt rsync module, same result running by bash command:

```
# salt 10.10.70.202 cmd.run '/usr/bin/rsync -avz --delete rsync://10.10.81.71:9999/test /tmp/test/ --password-file=/etc/rsync.passwd'
10.10.70.202:
    @ERROR: auth failed on module test
    rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1516) [Receiver=3.0.9]
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

However, same command working normally when I execute it on rsync client local machine(10.10.70.202):

```
#/usr/bin/rsync -avz --delete rsync://10.10.81.71:9999/test /tmp/test/ --password-file=/etc/rsync.passwd
receiving incremental file list

sent 54 bytes  received 108 bytes  324.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Rsync server config(10.10.81.71):

```
# cat /etc/rsyncd.conf
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
port = 9999
address = 10.10.81.71
uid = root
gid = root
use chroot = no
read only = no
max connections = 20
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
#motd file = /etc/rsyncd/rsyncd.motd
timeout = 300
auth users = root
secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets

[test]
path = /tmp/test/
read only = no

# cat /etc/rsyncd.secrets
root:applepen
```

Rsync client config(10.10.70.202):

```
# ls -l /etc/rsync.passwd 
-rw------- 1 root root 9 Jul  9 22:47 /etc/rsync.passwd

# cat /etc/rsync.passwd 
applepen
```

The error message same as rsync when password incorrect, so I guess if it related with salt didn't read correct password file's content:

```
# echo 'foobar' > /etc/rsync.passwd 
# /usr/bin/rsync -avz --delete rsync://10.10.81.71:9999/test /tmp/test/ --password-file=/etc/rsync.passwd
@ERROR: auth failed on module test
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1516) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

I also checked salt rsync module, didn't found useful info.
Salt version:

```
# salt --versions-report
           Salt: 2015.5.11
         Python: 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37)
         Jinja2: unknown
       M2Crypto: 0.20.2
 msgpack-python: 0.4.6
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.0.1
        libnacl: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.10
          ioflo: Not Installed
          PyZMQ: 14.3.1
           RAET: Not Installed
            ZMQ: 3.2.5
           Mako: Not Installed
        Tornado: Not Installed
        timelib: Not Installed
       dateutil: Not Installed
```

Any suggestion is greatly thankful!

[Update]
I deployed another salt environment with latest salt version, still can reproduce the issue, it might be a feature bug, decided to escalate this issue to saltstack.

```
# salt --versions-report
Salt Version:
           Salt: 2018.3.2

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: Not Installed
       cherrypy: Not Installed
       dateutil: Not Installed
      docker-py: Not Installed
          gitdb: Not Installed
      gitpython: Not Installed
          ioflo: Not Installed
         Jinja2: 2.8.1
        libgit2: Not Installed
        libnacl: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: Not Installed
           Mako: Not Installed
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.4.6
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
   pycryptodome: Not Installed
         pygit2: Not Installed
         Python: 2.7.13 (default, Mar 30 2018, 15:31:59)
   python-gnupg: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.11
          PyZMQ: 14.5.0
           RAET: Not Installed
          smmap: Not Installed
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.2.1
            ZMQ: 4.0.5

System Versions:
           dist: centos 6.5 Final
         locale: UTF-8
        machine: x86_64
        release: 2.6.32-431.11.25.el6.ucloud.x86_64
         system: Linux
        version: CentOS 6.5 Final
```

[Update]

Opened #[48517](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/48517) for tracking this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by setting the environment variables for inside of salt, salt didn't pass password file content or environment variable `RSYNC_PASSWORD` to rsync, it causing rsync auth failed.

```
# cat /srv/salt/set_rsync_env.sls
environment_variables:
  environ.setenv:
    - name: rsync
    - update_minion: True
    - value:
        USER: "root"
        RSYNC_PASSWORD: "applepen"

# salt 10.8.172.14 state.apply set_rsync_env
10.8.172.14:
----------
          ID: environment_variables
    Function: environ.setenv
        Name: rsync
      Result: True
     Comment: Environ values were set
     Started: 19:15:13.012966
    Duration: 7.606 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              RSYNC_PASSWORD:
                  applepen
              USER:
                  root

Summary for 10.8.172.14
------------
Succeeded: 1 (changed=1)
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     1
Total run time:   7.606 ms

# salt 10.10.70.202 cmd.run 'echo $USER $RSYNC_PASSWORD'
10.10.70.202:
    root applepen

# salt 10.10.70.202 cmd.run '/usr/bin/rsync -avz --delete rsync://10.10.81.71:9999/test /tmp/test/'
10.10.70.202:
    receiving incremental file list

    sent 54 bytes  received 108 bytes  108.00 bytes/sec
    total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```